# How do I use がする? (ex: いい香りがする)

Tags: grammar

I know the basic usage behind it, like saying "I wanna have lunch at Wendy's today", but I feel like there's a bunch of subtleties to it that I'm not really seeing yet

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  What is the relation between いい香りがする and “I wanna have lunch at Wendy's today”?

Comment: @Flaw: Are you talking about “…気がしない” (do not want to …)?  If so, this usage is limited to the negative form.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The way I understand it, the construction ~がする is used with intangible qualities the speaker wants something to have, like mentioned in the answer and the phrase 気がする, but it was never laid out in a concrete ways, with examples and such

Comment: “the construction ~がする is used with intangible qualities the speaker wants something to have, like mentioned in the answer”: The answer by Tim does not state that, and I do not think that …がする describes some qualities the speaker wants something to have.  Therefore, I am afraid that you may be still misunderstanding something about …がする.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Tsuyoshi, I see no obvious connection between いい香りがする and “I wanna have lunch at Wendy's today”.  I suspect you are confusing the expression 気がする with 気になる/気に入る but please clarify: it may be worthwhile sorting this out.

As for the use of する in 「いい香りがする」:

This is one of several uses of する not covered in the basic text books. In addition to its more conventional use (such as 日本語を勉強する), the verb する is also used in the following constructions to convey the following meanings:

１）To wear something, typically accessories such as マフラー, 腕時計 or ネクタイ.

> eg ネックレスをする | to wear a necklace.

(する is functioning as a 他動詞/transitive verb taking を.）

2) To sense something such as  におい、音、気、味

> eg Nのにおいがする | to smell N

(Where する is functioning as a 自動詞/intransitive verb  taking が.）

３） To cost an amount

> eg 家賃が１０万円もする

(Where する is functioning as a 自動詞/intransitive verb  which would normally take が but the amount works like adverb so が is omitted.）

*Reference: Japan Times 27 August 2012*