# Difference between 呼ぶ声がします and 呼びます

Tags: verbs

The full context of the first original phrase is:

> 「・・・浦島{うらしま}さん、・・・浦島さん」と、誰かが呼{よ}ぶ声｛こえ｝がします。

I was just wondering, why is 声がする in the sentence when there is already 呼ぶ? Or rather, what would be wrong with replacing 呼ぶ声がします with 呼びます?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 誰か**の**呼ぶ声がします？

Comment: ^ 「［誰か**が**呼ぶ］声がします」is also fine. 「［ジョン**の**買った］本」「［ジョン**が**買った］本」みたいな感じで・・ → https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12829/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「・・・浦島さん、・・・浦島さん」と、誰かが**呼ぶ声がします**。

> 「・・・浦島さん、・・・浦島さん」と、誰かが**呼びます**。

Both are *grammatically* correct.

In the former, 声がします expresses/implies that someone's voice came toward the main character (浦島太郎 here) and he hears it.

So the latter is just:

> Someone called, "Urashima-san, Urashima-san..."

while the original sounds more like:

> Taro heard someone's voice calling him, "Urashima-san, Urashima-san..."

---

The する here means "to sense/perceive".

> ［声・音・におい・香り・味・感じ・[気]{き} etc.］ + がする

is used to mean "to sense/perceive [voice, sound, smell, taste, feeling, etc.]"

eg

> 「声がする」 *hear a voice*
>   「～の音がする」 *hear the sound of ~*
>   「～のにおいがする」 *smell ~*

For more on this usage of する, you can refer to these threads:

- [「〜がする」 the extended use of する (to do)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17850/9831)
- [How do I use がする? (ex: いい香りがする)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11186/9831)
- [What does する mean when it does not mean "do"? （血のにおいがする）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2289/9831)

Answer (score 2):

So, in this case 呼ぶ声 is meant to be taken as a sort-of participle which means "a calling voice"/"a voice calling out". So the basic translation of what the sentence is - "'Urashima-san, Urashima-san', someone's voice called." You could use just "呼びます", the difference is mostly a stylistic one. Japanese uses "がします/する" instead of the literal verb, "call" in this case, to give the sentence a matter-of-fact feeling.